# A word that sounds like "yaky"

Tags: word-request

I was talking with a friend today, and he used a word that sounds like "yaky", where the "a" is pronounced the same way as the "a" in "father". Judging from the context, I think it describes something that he doesn't like. I tried to look for the word but could not find it. Could someone tell me what the word might be? Thanks!

Additional context:
It does not involve food. We were talking about math, and he describes the kind of analysis (a field of math) that he doesn't like as "yaky analysis".

Comment: It could be [*yucky*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yucky), used to talk about food but not only food.

Comment: does it mean [Yak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domestic_yak)-like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is *yucky*.

> [yucky](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/yucky)
>   adjective
>   disgusting or unpleasant:
>   *a yucky green colour*

I asked about food because it is often used with food, like *that cake was yucky!* However, it's not strictly used with food, as in the entry above.

He might have been trying to be funny, as *yucky* is commonly used with and by children.

Comment: Ah yes! That should actually be a short "uh" sound... thanks!